Find building plan for a (probably) Nanoblock set
Earlier today I was gifted this (what I assume to be) Nanoblock set, that a friend found while cleaning up the warehouse of a defunct musical instrument store.
(I say Nanoblock, because the dimensions of the bricks seem to match and they have ridges on the bottom too. Even though Nanoblock is rarely encountered here in The Netherlands.)
It is a musical instrument (supposedly a cello), but it appears to be put together rather badly. I also don't know if it is complete or not.
So I was wondering if I can find the building plan somewhere to correct/verify the build?


A bit of searching for "nanoblocks violin" yields https://www.nanoblock.com.sg/products/violin-nbc_018 (not to be confused with the later https://nanoblock.com.au/products/nanoblock-violin-2 ). And a bit of further searching aided by the "NBC-018" set number yields this image from https://blockguide.ch/2022/08/nbc-018/ :


That looks very much like it. The one I got has a another bow that goes with it and a longer neck. Maybe someone modified it a bit with the "extra blocks" that are supposedly included according to the leaflet.

Just rebuild the thing according to the supplied instructions. Got a 2x2 and a 2x1 in brown as extra. The short bow I got with the set didn't belong at all. Is totally unrelated.

I have been looking for cello as co-worker plays, with no luck. I have contrabass (= double bass) NBC_149 & violin NBC_018. About same size as each other. 1st has holes S shape, 2nd black in-lay.

There is already a perfectly valid and accepted answer, this one does not add anything to the topic.
